# Opencv cv::ximgproc::segmentation::SelectiveSearchSegmentation error

Tags: c++, opencv, image-segmentation, object-detection

I'm using Opencv and C++ to implement a selective search algorithm. I tried first with several images. However all of them return the same error.
The code is here:

```
#include "selective_search.h"  

using namespace std;  
using namespace cv;  
using namespace cv::ximgproc::segmentation;  

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  

    Mat img = imread("D:\\image.png", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    Ptr<SelectiveSearchSegmentation> gs = 
        createSelectiveSearchSegmentation();
    gs->setBaseImage(img);
    gs->switchToSelectiveSearchQuality();
    vector<Rect> rects;
    gs->process(rects);
}
```

and this error always appears when I run the line:

```
gs->process(rects);
```

I did some investigations an found out that the in the error happen in file **selectivesearchSegmentation.cpp** in function:

```
void SelectiveSearchSegmentationStrategyTextureImpl::setImage(InputArray img_, InputArray regions_, InputArray sizes_, int image_id)
```

at this last line of:

```
// X, rot
Scharr(img_plane_rotated, tmp_gradiant, CV_32F, 1, 0);

center = Point((int)(img_plane_rotated.cols / 2.0), (int)(img_plane_rotated.rows / 2.0));
rot = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(center, -45.0, 1.0);
warpAffine(tmp_gradiant, tmp_rot, rot, bbox.size());

tmp_gradiant = tmp_rot(Rect((bbox.width - img.cols) / 2, (bbox.height - img.rows) / 2, img.cols, img.rows));
```

The error happen because after the rotation, the value of

```
bbox.width - img.cols
```

can be smaller than zero. (such as in my case the image has dimension: 227x640)

Is this a bug in the library or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please, post code as text, not just screenshots. Use a debugger to find which statement causes this error. When you identify that, inspect the value of the input variables used in the statement. Finally, validate the results returned by functions that may fail (e.g. `imread`) and handle such cases appropriately.

Comment: @Dan: thank you! My c++ code is here: #include "selective_search.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::ximgproc::segmentation;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 
  Mat img = imread("D:\\image.png", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
  /*Ptr<SelectiveSearchSegmentation> gs = createSelectiveSearchSegmentation();
  gs->setBaseImage(img);
  gs->switchToSelectiveSearchQuality();
  vector<Rect> rects;
  gs->process(rects);*/

Comment: OK. Keep in mind you can always [edit] your question. As you can see yourself, comments are not ideal for large chunks of code. I did it for you this time :) | Now, the next step -- use a debugger to identify which statement causes this error.

Comment: @Dan, Thank you very much. This is the first time I post a question. I edited my question. Hope it is more clear now.